# create a temporary file with unpredictable name

Tags: c, linux, temporary-files, mktemp

When we create temporary files using tmpfile, in most cases we cannot easily predict the name. Coverity scan also complains about its vulnerability.
So is there any function to create a temporary file which cannot be guessed easily?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What you can do is generate a random string (please search internet how to do this) and use this random string to name your file in `fopen()`.

Comment: I was looking for a similar function like tmpfile, Of course I can choose to call fopen, but if there is already a function why should I write ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Linux, then [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html)

Or use `tmpnam`

Comment: `mkstemp()` also has some security issues, Refer [this link](http://www.securiteam.com/unixfocus/6H00S0K6AA.html).

Comment: Tag is C not C++      .

Comment: Edit my answer: change std::tmpnam to tmpnam from stdio.h